# How to open and control a chrome window using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I'm writing an application using node.js which requires me to open a window in a browser and fill a text field.
I have tried using opn. Fact is it just opens the tab but doesnt  allow me to control it.

Answer (score 0):

these kinds of stuff mostly helpful for acceptence testing and you can do it using "selenium"

other wise if you just want to open a window and fill a text field.

I believe the page you are trying to open is already been generated. if yes, then why don't you modify that page to accept a query string e.g: "?q=some-text" and fill that text field if you find.

Let me know if you have any other question

Comment: Thing is I dont have access to the page and i wanted to do this one without any webdrivers. You can keep an assumption that i can bypass cross site requests error.Thanks